# Inequality of converging sequences, and their limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I found the following question in my calculus text book in the section about boundness, relation, and the squeeze theorem:

Let $a_n \rightarrow a$, $b_n \rightarrow b$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $a_n < b_n+1$. Then $a < b+1$.

Does the following counter-example hold?

Take $a_n = \big(-\frac{1}{n}\big)_{n=1}^\infty$, and $b_n = \big(-1\big)_{n=1}^\infty$. Indeed $a_n < b_n +1 = -1+1=0$ for all $n$, but $ 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} b(n) +1=0$. Therefore the strict inequality does not hold.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. A limit of strict inequalities can become an equality, as your example shows. Perhaps you need a new textbook. :)

Comment: Thank you!
It was an exercise (one of the first in this chapter, of the "prove or give a counter example" kind)

Comment: Ah. Perhaps you should work on the phrasing you used when asking your question here -- you certainly conveyed the impression that you'd been given this to prove.

Comment: I will, thank you